# Scraping a dynamically created XHR URL

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, scrape, netflix

I'm trying to batch-save subtitles for Netflix shows using my personal account for access. The subtitles are loaded via XHR, and the URL is not directly present in the source code. It looks something like this:

`https://ipv4-c006-fra002-dev-ix.1.oca.nflxvideo.net/?o=AQO5Qr89pduVFe3zO7-r7O1Ll8Pt3P8F1yHLpVk7daGXhgXK56Cue7i7YCdfn6V7PkYS8MBUERCIHenyjcsiq-Yf5b-zSeuWTJgZwich5rv56YM2wgT1Jd2vKqeH-aj9TE3678UteuPYcRAOMHV76f0RRLc&v=5&e=1579480502&t=I4LI4nDvLpjvw-VYitSDoSHIsF8`, which if followed directly allows you to download a regular .vtt subtitle file for the episode in question. Obviously, this URL is generated by the heavily obfuscated Javascript frontend. Is it possible to obtain the necessary URL without resorting to Puppeteer/Selenium/PhantomJS?